# Keycloak Forget password link not open any form to enter password

Tags: docker, jboss, keycloak

I created a new docker with latest keycloak image jboss/keycloak:4.5.0.Final. Created new realm and client with added forgot password all other default settings .
Then i created a new user and while trying to login, i clicked on forgot password.
It sent a link via mail to reset password.
I clicked on link and it shows a message "YOUR ACCOUNT HAS BEEN UPDATED."

I expected it to present a form to allow enter new password.
I tried to search on web and in keycloak docs, but nothing there about in which situation it don't present form to enter new password when click on forget password link.

please help to identify what's i'm doing wrong?

Logs form keycloak:

```
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,066 TRACE [org.keycloak.events] (default task-21) type=SEND_RESET_PASSWORD, realmId=test, clientId=test-web, userId=3acdea4a-f035-4eec-a417-dd6dfc314cce, ipAddress=192.168.1.216, auth_method=openid-connect, auth_type=code, 
redirect_uri=http://localhost:343, code_id=b694032d-c7f3-499d-a531-46834025898e, email=test@test.com, username=test@test.com, requestUri=http://192.168.1.216:81/auth/realms/test/login-actions/reset-credentials?session_code=0bPI4Z2HKMtGqtzVvc9ph5T7j9QfehIJLt-m_10uxic&execution=2842aded-c525-427c-ba13-96dd4d4db903&client_id=test-web&tab_id=iHtfvDaO_Us, cookies=
[KC_RESTART=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJiMjk2NDk0OS1jMjAwLTRkNDMtOWYyOC1mZjU2YWU3ZDhhOGMifQ.eyJjaWQiOiJhbXN5cy13ZWIiLCJwdHkiOiJvcGVuaWQtY29ubmVjdCIsInJ1cmkiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjM0MyIsImFjdCI6IkFVVEhFTlRJQ0FURSIsIm5vdGVzIjp7ImlzcyI6Imh0
dHA6Ly8xOTIuMTY4LjEuMjE2OjgxL2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL2Ftc3lzIiwicmVzcG9uc2VfdHlwZSI6ImNvZGUiLCJyZWRpcmVjdF91cmkiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjM0MyIsImNvZGVfY2hhbGxlbmdlX21ldGhvZCI6InBsYWluIn19.Hs8K3iAe2mofUpx48G8wznEtIczLC2hIhEDeQjc88XM, AUTH_SESSION_ID=b694032d-c7f3-499d-a531-46834025898e.1b2a99930ee9]
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,066 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-21) reset browser login from authenticator: reset-credential-email
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,066 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanKeycloakTransaction] (default task-21) Adding cache operation: REPLACE on b694032d-c7f3-499d-a531-46834025898e
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,066 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession] (default task-21) client by id cache hit: test-web
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,066 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanKeycloakTransaction] (default task-21) Adding cache operation: REPLACE on b694032d-c7f3-499d-a531-46834025898e
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,066 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanKeycloakTransaction] (default task-21) Adding cache operation: REPLACE on b694032d-c7f3-499d-a531-46834025898e
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,066 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanKeycloakTransaction] (default task-21) Adding cache operation: REPLACE on b694032d-c7f3-499d-a531-46834025898e
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,066 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanKeycloakTransaction] (default task-21) Adding cache operation: REPLACE on b694032d-c7f3-499d-a531-46834025898e
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,066 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanKeycloakTransaction] (default task-21) Adding cache operation: REPLACE on b694032d-c7f3-499d-a531-46834025898e
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,066 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanKeycloakTransaction] (default task-21) Adding cache operation: REPLACE on b694032d-c7f3-499d-a531-46834025898e
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,066 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanKeycloakTransaction] (default task-21) Adding cache operation: REPLACE on b694032d-c7f3-499d-a531-46834025898e
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,066 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanKeycloakTransaction] (default task-21) Adding cache operation: REPLACE on b694032d-c7f3-499d-a531-46834025898e
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,066 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession] (default task-21) client by id cache hit: test-web
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,066 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor] (default task-21) Forked authSession Ae49PjFP1C4 from authSession iHtfvDaO_Us . Client: test-web, Root session: b694032d-c7f3-499d-a531-46834025898e
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,066 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanKeycloakTransaction] (default task-21) Adding cache operation: REPLACE on b694032d-c7f3-499d-a531-46834025898e
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,066 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession] (default task-21) client by id cache hit: test-web
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor] (default task-21) AUTHENTICATE
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor] (default task-21) AUTHENTICATE ONLY
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanKeycloakTransaction] (default task-21) Adding cache operation: REPLACE on b694032d-c7f3-499d-a531-46834025898e
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession] (default task-21) client by id cache hit: test-web
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-21) processFlow
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-21) check execution: auth-cookie requirement: ALTERNATIVE
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-21) authenticator: auth-cookie
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-21) invoke authenticator.authenticate: auth-cookie
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services.managers.AuthenticationManager] (default task-21) Could not find cookie: KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-21) authenticator ATTEMPTED: auth-cookie
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanKeycloakTransaction] (default task-21) Adding cache operation: REPLACE on b694032d-c7f3-499d-a531-46834025898e
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-21) check execution: auth-spnego requirement: DISABLED
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-21) execution is processed
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-21) check execution: identity-provider-redirector requirement: ALTERNATIVE
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-21) authenticator: identity-provider-redirector
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-21) invoke authenticator.authenticate: identity-provider-redirector
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 TRACE [org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.IdentityProviderAuthenticator] (default task-21) No default provider set or kc_idp_hint query parameter provided
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-21) authenticator ATTEMPTED: identity-provider-redirector
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanKeycloakTransaction] (default task-21) Adding cache operation: REPLACE on b694032d-c7f3-499d-a531-46834025898e
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-21) check execution: null requirement: ALTERNATIVE
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-21) execution is flow
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-21) processFlow
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-21) check execution: auth-username-password-form requirement: REQUIRED
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-21) authenticator: auth-username-password-form
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-21) invoke authenticator.authenticate: auth-username-password-form
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanKeycloakTransaction] (default task-21) Adding cache operation: REPLACE on b694032d-c7f3-499d-a531-46834025898e
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,067 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanKeycloakTransaction] (default task-21) Adding cache operation: REPLACE on b694032d-c7f3-499d-a531-46834025898e
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,068 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession] (default task-21) client by id cache hit: test-web
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,085 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-21) authenticator CHALLENGE: auth-username-password-form
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,087 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanKeycloakTransaction] (default task-21) Adding cache operation: REPLACE on b694032d-c7f3-499d-a531-46834025898e
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,087 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanKeycloakTransaction] (default task-21) Adding cache operation: REPLACE on b694032d-c7f3-499d-a531-46834025898e
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,088 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession] (default task-21) client by id cache hit: test-web
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,089 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (default task-21) JtaTransactionWrapper  commit
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,089 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (default task-21) JtaTransactionWrapper end
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,179 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (default task-21) new JtaTransactionWrapper
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,180 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (default task-21) was existing? false
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,185 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (default task-21) JtaTransactionWrapper  commit
keycloak_1        | 13:21:20,185 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (default task-21) JtaTransactionWrapper end
```

Comment: It seems that you're following such an strange flow.. For me the normal thing to do when registering a new user would be to access the keycloak page through the new user link and set a password there. I think the forget password link is designed to work for users that have already been completely created (this means having set their first password).

Comment: Thanks, but i tried that as well, completed initial flow, updated initial password by user and then tried Forgot password, but still same issue

Comment: Also users need to set their first password only if update password enabled in required action, although i tried both ways but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported it to jboss keycloak jira and they accepted it as an issue https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-8571